# How to display icon arc of doughnut chart with primeVue

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, primevue

I use Primevue V3 to make doughnuts charts but i don't know how to display something in arc of doughnuts charts. I have found the plugins chartjs-plugin-labels to display something but i don't know how to use it with PrimeVue.

My Vue file

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Chart ref="primeChart" type="doughnut" :data="chartData" :options="lightOptions" />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup >
import {ref} from "vue";
const chartData = ref({
  labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [300, 50, 100],
      backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"]
    }
  ]
 });
    const lightOptions = ref({
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true
   }
 }
});
 </script>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`chartjs-plugin-labels` is for legacy versions of Chart.js. Use [`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) for Chart.js 3 or newer.

The PrimeVue `Chart` component has a `plugins` property that receives an array of Chart.js plugins to use:

```html
<script setup>
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'
const plugins = [ChartDataLabels]
⋮
</script>

<template>
  <Chart :plugins="plugins" ⋯ />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-primevue-chart-labels?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: With chartjs-plugin-datalabels, is it possible to change label with icon ?